# Selecting indexed item froman element in a two dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, multidimensional-array, each

I am unsure how to select the second item from each array in a two-dimensional array given a condition on the first. Here is a similar example to what I am trying to accomplish:

If you have a 2-dimensional array in Ruby, `[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']]`, how could you create an array with only the letters that are in an array with an even number? (Assuming each sub-array has the same format: *[number, letter]*)

Although this code does not work, I assumed a solution would be similar to:

```
array1 = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']]
array2 = array1.each do |num, letter|
  if num.even?
    return letter
  end
end
```

I want the value of array2 after running this to be `['b', 'd']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with collect and compact combination:

`array1.collect { |num, letter| letter if num.even? }.compact`

First, you `collect` all the results of the if statement, then you `compact` to remove all the `nil` occurrences.

Comment: Does this alter the original array as well? --edit: I have tested it and it does not; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.each_with_object([]) { |(n,s),arr| arr << s if n.even? }
  #=> ["b", "d"]
```

I would have added explanatory comments but could not find anything that required explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For verbosity, select every array where the number is even, and then map their last element:

```
array1.select { |num, _| num.even? }.map(&:last)
# ["b", "d"]
```